# Bluemix-> Get application: Address already in use

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to add a git repository to my application in Bluemix but when I try I get this message of error:

"An error occured when performing operation Get application: Address already in use"

Have someone any idea about what happens?

Thank you for your help,

Filippo.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to say, but it looks as if Bluemix tries to bind to a specific local port, that's already open.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Do you konw how to find out which local port Bluemix is trying to bind?

Comment: Not any trivial way. It may be possibel to start BLuemix and use `lsof -p <pid of bluemix>` to see if it has any local port bound. Failing that, tehre may be something in the manual.

Comment: Thank you Vatine ;)